# How to remove a string, between two delimiters, at the end of a line?

Tags: python, parsing, syslog-ng

So I want to remove the last statement in my rule, the rule structure goes like this:

```
<pattern> @rule statements go here@ @multiple rule statements@ @remain all on the same line@</pattern>
```

The parsing statements will always be between the @ characters, and I would like to remove the last statement in the line.

I can use regex to remove everything in-between the @ characters:

```
re.sub(r'@.+?@', '', s)
```

How can I make that happen for only the last statement in the line, when each line will be different from one another?

Comment: Also consider simple string processing: `rfind` and slicing.

Comment: Just to be clear, the string at the end will be different every rule, and will not able to be explicitly searched for. I haven't looked into rfind or slicing yet, so I can't comment on their effectiveness, I just wanted to clear any potential misconceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(\@[^\@]+)\@?$
```

The above regex will search for the last occurrence of @ then work backwards to achieve a full match of the last @string@ occurrenc, in the example string below "@remain all on the same line@" will be matched

```
@rule statements go here@ @multiple rule statements@ @remain all on the same line@
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a [negative lookahead assertion](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/re.html#index-21) we can make sure to only remove the last occurrence:

```
re.sub(r'@[^@]+@(?!.*@)', '', s)
```

(Note that I needed to change `.+?` to `[^@]+` to explicitly exclude `@`, otherwise it will match all `@statements@` at once.)